# Cannot get tailwind 3.3.2 to work in Angular 16.1.4

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

my component.html reads

```
<mat-toolbar class="max-w-7xl mx-auto border-x justify-between">
   <a routerLink="home">code with nige</a>
   <mat-icon>shopping_cart</mat-icon>
</mat-toolbar>
```

when i run my app none of the tailwind styles are working,
i am using chrome browser, i have opened devtools and typed in justify-between in mat-toolbar styles and then it worked
can someone point me in the correct direction to solve this issue